# how to know that a data message was received when the app was in background?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When the app is in **background** and receive a data message, the delivery of the data message is delayed and the app will receive this message when it's will become **foreground** via `messagingDidReceiveMessage`. When the app is foreground then it's will receive the data message directly on `messagingDidReceiveMessage`

My problem: how to know in `messagingDidReceiveMessage` that the data message was received when the app was in background and was waiting the app go foreground ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`messagingDidReceiveMessage` is used to receive messages that bypass APNs and are sent directly to your app from FCM. This is only available when a connection is open between your app and FCM, this is only available when the app is in the foreground.

To receive data messages when your app is in the background you need to use the APNs callbacks. You can still send data messages through FCM when your app is in the background but you can't use the `messagingDidReceiveMessage` callback in that case.